# How to enable named groups at Bouncy Castle JSSE (1.68)?

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve, jsse

I want to create a Java TLS server with support of `brainpoolP512r1` using Bouncy Castle 1.68 JSSE. I thought it would be enough to list it with system property `jdk.tls.namedGroups` but this only leads to this output:

```
2021-02-17T13:14:17,240 ERROR - Feb 17, 2021 1:14:17 PM org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.NamedGroupInfo createCandidates
WARNING: 'jdk.tls.namedGroups' contains disabled NamedGroup: brainpoolP512r1
```

I literally can't find anything on this topic using Google. I've found the [BCJSSE-PDF](https://downloads.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BC-FJA-(D)TLSUserGuide-1.0.9.pdf) at bouncycastle.org. And I've read quiet a big part of the TLS source code at Github. But I can't make sense of this problem. Thankful for any hints!

Edit: I just found something suspicious in the JSSE code: [ECUtil.java](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/b9891bd460a7a938cf642444a0164d5e5c94fba2/tls/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/tls/crypto/impl/jcajce/ECUtil.java#L138). Maybe it is important that I am using AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.10+9?

Comment: Just tested with Java Oracle 8 VM - problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better when the providers are placed up front with the JSSE provider being the first. My "disabled named group" error disappeared. I don't even have to use `jdk.tls.namedGroups` anymore.

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider(), 1);
```